# Why does my mechanic suggest me to press the clutch when spark plugs tend to flood?

Tags: fuel-system

I'm quite a novice when it comes to mechanics of a car.

I had a problem recently in my car where it wouldn't start. The mechanic explained that the plugs are flooding and maintenance is needed (a third party took the car, so I don't have more details). Before maintenance, the mechanic suggested that I try to start with the clutch pressed down, and it worked. He said something about fuel being cut off when the clutch is down (again, through a third party) and therefore no flooding of the plugs. But this doesn't seem to make sense to me. If the fuel is cut off, how can the engine start overall? And what kind of a role does the clutch play when it comes to fuel flow? Can somebody make sense of what the mechanic was trying to say? The car is a Renault Twingo.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Doesn't make much sense to me either. If you're trying to start the car, why would you want the fuel cutoff? Most manual shift vehicles I've driven require you to press the clutch (neutral safety switch) to ensure the vehicle isn't in gear when you go to start it ... so, having the clutch pedal pressed down to cut fuel seems counter productive to getting the engine started in the first place. Really don't know what the mechanic was talking about.

Comment: Is it miscommunication? Maybe he meant or said to put the gas pedal all the way down. This puts it in flood mode. It reduces or cuts of fuel supply to start a flooded engine.

Comment: @Jupiter That used to work when cars had mechanical carburetors and manual chokes for cold starting (it let more air through the cylinders to evaporate the excess fuel), but an electronic engine control system shouldn't flood the engine in the first place so I would be surprised if it does anything at all.

Comment: Most if not all fuel injected engines have a flood mode when cranking with the gas pedal all the way down. It not only allows more air but also command lite or no fuel to the injectors.
 Its actually called flood mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years ago when manual xmissions were popular, the standard starting method was to depress the clutch pedal to unload the xmission gear box from loading the engine then starting. This also prevents the vehicle from inadvertently moving if it was left in gear on a hill to help prevent the vehicle from moving even with the parking brake engaged and steering wheels turned into the curb. Those older vehicles can start in gear without the clutch pedal depressed. Updated vehicles with manual xmissions have a starter disable switch on the clutch pedal assembly. If the clutch pedal isn't depressed, the starter interrupt switch disables starting. Depressing the clutch pedal closes the the start safety switch to allow starting.